# Running a Runnable Thead multiple times (Android)

Tags: java, android, tcp, tcpclient

I posted a question earlier that you helped me with and advanced me significantly in my project and was looking for one last piece of help.

I have a Java TCP Server running on my laptop, it just constantly reads the lines that are given over that TCP port. I am 100% positive that function is working, I tested it without the android app.

My issue lies somewhere in this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private String serverIpAddress = "10.30.13.110";
private int serverPort = 50505;
private boolean connected = false;
private char launchercontrolcode;
Button button1;
ImageButton button2, button3, button4, button5, button6;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.armbutton);
    button1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button2 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.firebutton);
    button2.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button3 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.upbutton);
    button3.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button4 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.downbutton);
    button4.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button5 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.leftbutton);
    button5.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    button6 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.rightbutton);
    button6.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
}


private OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
            case R.id.armbutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'A';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                    for(int i =0 ; i<10; i++);
                }
            break;
            case R.id.firebutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'F';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            break;
            case R.id.upbutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'U';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            break;
            case R.id.downbutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'D';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            break;
            case R.id.leftbutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'L';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            break;
            case R.id.rightbutton:
                if (!connected) {
                    launchercontrolcode = 'R';
                    Thread cThread = new Thread(new ClientThread());
                    cThread.start();
                }
            break;
        }
    }
};

public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, serverPort);
                connected = true;
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "Client Connected");
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        out.println(launchercontrolcode);
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Cliend Sent Code");
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "Post-socket close");
                } catch (Exception e) {     
            connected = false; 

        }
    }
}
}
```

My issue is that if I press the first button, it gets sent to the server fine; however, when I press the second (or X) time, it will NOT send to the server for some reason. I am fairly confident the problem lies within my switch statement, but not sure what it exactly is.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: how about when you press the first button again what happen?

Comment: Still nothing, just the very first button press works, nothing after registers

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that once you enter that thread.. boolean connection is set to true but when you are done and close all the connection it is still true..

why?? because it is inside the catch it should never be there.. if you want to click another button again.. you are waiting for an exception to click again..

**solution:**

```
public class ClientThread implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
            try {
                Socket socket = new Socket(serverIpAddress, serverPort);
                connected = true;
                Log.d("ClientActivity", "Client Connected");
                    try {
                        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);
                        out.println(launchercontrolcode);
                        Log.d("ClientActivity", "Cliend Sent Code");
                        out.flush();
                        out.close();
                    } catch (Exception e) {}
                    socket.close();
                    Log.d("ClientActivity", "Post-socket close");
                } catch (Exception e) {      

        }finally{
          connected = false;
      }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, I missed that variable declaration in the parent class and assumed it was a typo.

Comment: @jgitter yea I just noticed that connected was inside the catch that it will never be false again once it catches an error

Comment: That worked, Thank you! Also, I know that Wifi probably isnt going to be the fastest method for sending the codes but do you have any recommendations to shorten the time it takes?